# Access token return access denied when call WEB API endpoint method secured with Azure app

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, bearer-token, azure-ad-msal

Setup MSAL IOS Swift app sample with Client ID (native app registered as part of the tutorial)

I am getting Unauthorised error every time I call WebAPI endpoint method in my website to retrieve user object with it's ID through postman with Key Authorisation and Value Bearer + Token (retrieved from successful Azure AD user auth),

My Value are as follows:

```
let kClientID = "my native app id"  
    // These settings you don't need to edit unless you wish to attempt deeper scenarios with the app.
    let kGraphURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/"
    let kScopes: [String] = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read"]
    let kAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
```

PS : My Web APP authentication via Azure calling same endpoints are working fine, Issue is only with native app, i can't figure where could i be going wrong, I have spent days on it with no joy, Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess your request contained the parameter "client_secret",whereas for native app,it is not required,another reason is that the access token does not contain the impersonation permissions required to access the resource,impersonation permissions granted to the native client application. The default permission is user_impersonation. The owner of the target resource can register alternate values in Azure AD,you can also click this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) and search "native" to find out the reason,hope it benefit.